adb total number of possible swipes
I have an android program that I want to interact with using adb, the problem is that I wouldn't know how many swipes are required to go through all elements.
I already swipe through UI using
adb shell input swipe 250 400 250 800 100


then dumps UI using
adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty

if the current hierarchy is as same as the previous one, then I conclude that I reached the end of elements that can be swiped. It works most of the times however when the hierarchies are same but has different ImageView fails, since the content of the image is not reflected in the hierarchy xml.
So, is there any way to let me know total number of possible swipes?
Thanks

You haven't provided any details about the application or how are the layouts and conditions you want to detect
